# Monaca IDEのプレビューに端末を登録したい

Tags: monaca

Monaca IDEにはプレビュー機能が付いていて、いくつかの端末サイズがプリセットされています。ここに、あたらしい端末（画面サイズ）を追加することはできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

運営会社に直接問い合わせたところ、現在のところ、画面サイズの追加は出来ないとのことでした。